# how get this specific format of date in pre-request of postman

Tags: datetime, postman, postman-pre-request-script

I have this in c#:

```
var date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and the result is like this:

```
date = "Tue, 27 Dec 2022 13:30:35 GMT";
```

I want to have this result in pre-request of postman to pass this variable as date.
But this command doesn't give me the exact result:

```
var date = new Date();
//result:  Tue Dec 27 2022 16:26:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

As I'm using this date variable for encryption, it's important to have it in the special format I have in c#.

Do you have any idea how can I have this result in postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display time, you can use `momentjs`, that's already included in postman. The cons is it doesn't support timezone, so the code would be:

```js
const moment = require('moment')
let datetime = moment().format("ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss ") + "GMT"
//Wed, 28 Dec 2022 08:08:36 GMT
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reg expression in `pre-request` section

```
var date = new Date();
// Tue Dec 27 2022 12:10:39 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
console.log(date);
let match = /(Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat)\s+(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+(\d{1,2})\s+(\d{4})\s+(\d{2}|\d{1})\:(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\s([a-zA-Z]{3})/.exec(date);
// 0: "Tue Dec 27 2022 12:10:39 GMT"
// 1: "Tue"
// 2: "Dec"
// 3: "27"
// 4: "2022"
// 5: "12"
// 6: "10"
// 7: "39"
// 8: "GMT"
// newDate = "Tue, 27 Dec 2022 13:30:39 GMT";
newDate = `${match[1]}, ${match[3]} ${match[2]} ${match[4]} ${match[5]}:${match[6]}:${match[7]} ${match[8]}`
console.log(newDate);
```

Result in console

```
 
Tue Dec 27 2022 12:22:39 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
 
Tue, 27 Dec 2022 12:22:39 GMT
```

[image]

Test string set in `https://regex101.com/`

Regular Expression

```
(Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat)\s+(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+(\d{1,2})\s+(\d{4})\s+(\d{2}|\d{1})\:(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\s([a-zA-Z]{3})
```

[image]

In  Reg Expression Visualization `https://regexper.com/`

[image]